# Scrapy - Page Access Denied

Tags: python, scrapy, scrapy-splash

I am looking for some help for scraping www.mobile.de, while I get an "Access Denied Page"
A regular spider results in the attached picture.
So far I have tried/recognized:
I am not blocked, since I can open the page in Firefox/Chrome

- I allowed cookies
- I used the same header as used currently by Firefox
- I used a referer
- I enabled/disabled "Obey robots.txt"
- I used Splash to activate/render Javascript

So right now, I cannot conclude how the page detects that my program is a bot and how to avoid that.

https://ibb.co/7RsMkM3

Comment: try requesting the page without splash, if it is not banned your problem is with splash adding headers

Comment: I tried without Splash, but still got the problem. 
I just tried it with Splash in the first place, because the error page says to activate cookies and javascript.
Anyway, to make it more precise, this is the link to the page I am trying to access:
https://suchen.mobile.de/fahrzeuge/search.html?adLimitation=ONLY_FSBO_ADS&damageUnrepaired=NO_DAMAGE_UNREPAIRED&isSearchRequest=true&maxPowerAsArray=PS&minPowerAsArray=PS&scopeId=C&sfmr=false

Comment: cookies are enabled by default, so no need to worry about them

Comment: Okay, so I used a regular spider without Splash, enabled Cookies, disabled robots.txt, used an up-to-date header, included a referer, but still receive an "Access denied", while not being blocked, since I can access the page with my regular browser.

Comment: this is a honeypot link